# React - how to 'split' an array to give line breaks

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have an array, let's say:

```
["One", "Two", "Three"]
```

And I'd like to render it as a string on separate lines with "`<br/>`" between each element as:

```
One<br/>Two<br/>Three
```

so that they'll render as separate lines.  What I'd use in a text-based system would be something like:

```
my_array.join("\n")
```

So what I want is the equivalent of:

```
my_array.join(<br/>)
```

But that doesn't work in something like:

```
return <div>{my_array.join(<br/>)}</div>;
```

as it returns objects instead of what I'm looking for:

```
One[object Object]Two[object Object]Three
```

Note that I DON'T want a trailing `<br/>` at the end - I understand I could use a map for that.

To save you reading further, the solution I used is:

```
my_array.map((item, index) => index ? <><br/>{item}</> : <>{item}</>)
```

which does use a map but utilises the index to place a `<br/>` before every element but the first.

Comment: In the map function, you can just check if it's the last element. If it's the last element don't append <br/>

Comment: Or, as the answer below gives, use the index to place a `<br/>` BEFORE every element except the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
["One", "Two", "Three"].map((item, index) => {
  if (index === 0) {
    return <>{item}</>
  }
  return <><br/>{item}</>
})
```

Comment: Excellent.  I've marked this as the accepted answer as it led me to what I actually used, which was `my_array.map((item, index) => index ? <><br/>{item}</> : <>{item}</>)`

Comment: what a champ, saved me so much time

Answer (score 0):

I think you can edit the each string array value and put the line break in to it .
you need to use map function.

```
 <div>{my_array.join.map((item, index) => 
                        
                      <span>  {item}<br/></span>
                   )}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's going to put a <br/> on the end of the list, which I don't want.

Comment: ok then you can put the check like `<div>{my_array.join.map((item, index) => if(index+1!=my_array.length){ <span> {item}<br/></span> } )}</div>` so it will not put the br tag for last item

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
    let arr = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
    return (
        <div>
            {[...arr.map(item => <div key={item}>{item}</div>), <br key={'br'}/>]}
        </div>
    );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Don't forget that it is important to include a unique key prop for each element in the array to ensure that React can efficiently update the list.

Hope it helped!